# How can i export my 3D animation for 3D video?

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view

I have simpe 3D animation. I want to view watch this animation with 3D glasses and 3D projection. How can i convert to my 3D animation? 
Look at the picture for more information: [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J56c6.jpg)
http://directetnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/3d-film-indir.jpg

Picture:

[image]

Comment: If you mean how can you convert a stereo-anaglyph image or video into a 3D scene then no clue - would be a neat trick though!!! have a look at this thread- https://blenderartists.org/t/stereo-picture-into-3d-mesh/538276 If you don't mean that, please explain more...

Comment: No. my mean is not this. Opposite what you say. I have a 3D model in blender. I want to tereo-anaglyph image or video..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, here-
[image: Settings in 'Output Properties' tab hi-lighted]

Looks like it works in Cycles and Eevee, but the rendered viewport display in Cycles is very broken, and has been a bug since March 2019; https://developer.blender.org/T62582
It does render (F12) OK by the looks of it.
It outputs 2 images from the L/R cameras in 'Stereo 3D' mode, so you'll have to join them into a single Anaglyph image.
If you use 'MultiView' mode it will output an Anaglyph image, but you need 2 cameras in the scene, with '_L' and '_R' suffixes on their names, and you'll have to manually set their position / convergence.

Cheers
Mark